# Keeping my image responsive and aspect rational?

Tags: html, css, image, aspect-ratio

How do I achieve this magic?
http://aprendagames.com/stock/brokebot/errorpages-headless-robot.html?errorcode=404

I'm in similar situation. I need an image that will keep the center position while it can fit the screen. After that just keeping aspect ratio.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far? We can't really help you if we don't know where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="img" src="...">
</div>
```

css

```
.container{
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.container img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 200px; /*change to fit your image*/
}
```

The max-width on the img tag is set to 200px to serve the example, set it to the maximum width you want your image to get to.

here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hzpd04va/